# Installing using Virtual Box

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, virtualization

So I thought this would be easy....

1. Downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 ISO
2. Burned ISO onto CD using Roxio
3. Created a 20Gb VM partition (.vdi) using VirtualBox
4. In VirtualBox went into settings, system and moved CD to the top of my boot order
5. In storage , under the "Controller IDE" section I selected my Host CD drive D:\

Here's where it goes pear shaped,

I assumed that I could then hit "Start" and Ubuntu would boot from the ISO which is on my D:\ drive.......wrong! I get the following error -

```
Error relaunching Virtualbox VM process: 5
Command Line :81954AF5-4D2DF-31EB-A142-B7AF187A1C41-suplib-2ndchild
-comment Memtwo --startvm e83b91d8-2147-4410-a8a1-67e264224054
-no-startvm-errormsgbox' (rc=104)
```

Sounds serious!!

I've read several instructions on how to do what I am doing and it all seems straightforward but I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Please Help!!

Comment: are you on windows, right? Which version of VirtualBox do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a little easier than you've made it.

Instead of mounting the ISO as a separate disk, just start your newly created VM - the first thing it should do, is as for an ISO that contains the operating system which you can specify using a drop-down box.  The VM should then boot, mount and start loading from that.

[image]

Comment: Charles, thanks for your reply. Sadly my first attempt, after creating my VM partition in VirtualBox, was to hit the START button. Unfortunately I didn't see the same screen as you have posted.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: @Fortbill1 I did a little more research (And since I saw something similar yesterday I should have remembered) - Windows OS users hosting VirtualBox 4.3.14 are experiencing a lot of errors, perhaps related to Antivirus or a spurious registry entry.  Some people report the 4.3.15 beta works much better...  Please try following the attached thread https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62615

Comment: @CharlesGreen is right, Vbox 4.3 has problems, better download 4.2

Comment: @tttony I think from what I've read and my own experiences, the problem is limited to Windows hosts, and 4.3.14.  Since I don't run Windows except inside a VM, I have no easy way to test this.

Comment: So I've been playing around and as @CharlesGreen said I was making things difficult for myself trying to point to an ISO file on a CD. I attempted to point straight to the file on my HD and got a different error message which more or less suggested that this version was not supported....downloading older image now. Thanks again for your help and I'll let you know how I get on!!

Comment: @Fortbill1 An alternative is VMWare Player, which is also free for personal use.  It can be downloaded at https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads - look very close to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Went back as far as version 12.10 of Ubuntu with little success. Whilst VirtualBox will allow me to select the ISO from my hard drive and seems to point to the right place I get the same error message when I attempt to start the VM. Like you guys have suggested, it looks like it's VirtualBox that's the issue....this really shouldn't be so hard. I'll of course post my success later (got to try and be optimistic!!).

Comment: @Fortbill1  - the problem is not the Ubuntu version, it is the VirtualBox version.  There is something not quite right with VB 4.3.14 and Windows

Comment: @Charles Green...yeah I realized that I hadn't read your post correctly. Went back to older version of VirtualBox (4.3.12) and thankfully all is well. As we speak I am in the process of setting up Ubuntu. Thanks again for your help. Much appreciated!!

Comment: @CharlesGreen after some success installing Ubuntu 14.04 on Vbox 4.3 I've eventually moved to VMWare Player. Which seems to operate far better. Looks like I have a rather steep learning curve to get to grips with Lynux and Ubuntu but looking forward to the challenge.

Comment: @Fortbill1  I made the changeover some time ago - I still have WinXP, 7 and 8 running as guests in VMWare for some programs that do not work in Linux, but I'm pretty happy with the way things are working.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had many projects inside Ubuntu14.04 installed in VirtualBox and could not get them back because of this error.

I researched to try and find a solution as soon as I could because all my projects belong my company. It was not easy to format or re-install VirtualBox. However, I have now fixed this error. You may not believe it but try and see how this works.

Go to the website of VirtualBox and install the latest version. When you start installing it will ask you a few questions about oracle such as do you trust oracle  - the answer is yes. This message will be repeated a few times just click on install until finished.
After, start to open your VirtualBox and it will work 100%.

Let me explain how this error happens on my machine.  When I click on my Virtualbox to open it, it was a bit to slow and does not always start up and I try again by clicking.  Suddenly it opens and you I on the op system I want to open. After this I saw a few VirtualBox windows were open and I closed the ones I did not need.  It then suddenly closed the one I already clicked to start, and this error opened for me.  That is how my problem started and I did not have any problems before.

To fix this error  (Error relaunching Virtualbox VM process: 5) installing VirtualBox on the top will overwrite your actual machine and fix the error for you.

I hope that will help.

Best wishes

DilMac